# How to execute a small part of C Code in Python?

Tags: python, c

I have written a code in Python. There is a part in the code that does integration which has a very high computation time. But the same integration takes very less time in C. I want to run that part in C (that will take some input) and use the output to run the other code in python. In other words, I have a very large code in python, of which I want to run a small part in C. Please tell me how to do that.

Comment: First of all, show us at least a subset of both the Python code and the C code. It is a Python extension or regular C?

Comment: Without detail, I just recommend [SWIG](http://www.swig.org)

Comment: The title asks exactly the opposite of what the text says. Before using foreign languages (which of course is possible), try to speed up your Pytoh code. I've seen implrovements of 10 times and much more with just using Python correctly ("pythonify"). Also you might want to check out numpy.

Comment: I second the SWIG recommendation. Google it. You'll figure out how to use it in your code.

Comment: You might also try altering the code slightly by converting it to use cython. That's a python-like language which compiles to C, then to native code. It usually yields an enormous speedup for numerically heavy code. scipy also has optimized numerical integration code that might be a better choice overall: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ctypes.html) library.